# Precompiled opencv libraries for Mac

Tags: java, opencv

I don't have a Mac box, but my target user does. I'm looking for what I believe would be an 'libopencv_opencv341.jnilib' (or similar; '.dylib', maybe) file. I would then package that with my JAR and load it in with "System.load(new File(*library*.getAbsolutePath())".

Could someone kindly pass me a copy of their compiled opencv3+ java library. (Assuming this would be transferable; the windows .dll worked between machines.)

This would be the equivalent of libopencv_java341.so (linux) and opencv_java341.dll.

If it helps anyone, these are my .so & .dll builds for ubuntu18.04 & win10: https://www.transfernow.net/ddl/opencv341libs

much appreciated,

craig